# PHP file not being interpreted by Apache on Red Hat

Tags: apache-2.2, redhat, php5

Running PHP 5.3.3 through Apache 2.2.15, on Red Hat (kernel 2.6)

I have a test file in the root directory called test.php:

```
<?
  phpinfo();
?>
```

When I point my browser to this file, it sends me this source uninterpreted.

No errors are shown in the log, and the access log has a standard entry:

```
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [29/Nov/2012:10:26:56 -0500] "GET /test.php HTTP/1.1" 200 17 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.91 Safari/537.11"
```

My configuration file has the following lines:

/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
...
Include conf.d/*.conf
...
```

/etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf

```
#
# PHP is an HTML-embedded scripting language which attempts to make it
# easy for developers to write dynamically generated webpages.
#
<IfModule prefork.c>
  LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
</IfModule>
<IfModule worker.c>
  LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5-zts.so
</IfModule>

#
# Cause the PHP interpreter to handle files with a .php extension.
#
AddHandler php5-script .php
AddType text/html .php

#
# Add index.php to the list of files that will be served as directory
# indexes.
#
DirectoryIndex index.php

#
# Uncomment the following line to allow PHP to pretty-print .phps
# files as PHP source code:
#
#AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
```

No errors are logged at startup, which suggests that the modules are indeed being loaded in correctly.

This is all out-of-the-box configuration, so I'm really surprised this doesn't just work.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

*Sigh* Why is it that, after hours of searching, you find nothing.  But then get the answer 2 minutes after posting to SO?

So, whatever site I copied that test file from didn't take into consideration that short tags are off by default.  Changing the test file to

```
<?php
  phpinfo();
?>
```

fixed everything.